# C++ Linked List: variable issue

Tags: list, c++11

```
struct List
{
     Post *p;  //a random class
     List *next;    
};
```

and i use this to insert data

```
List *help;
help=(*leaf)->start; //leaf is a node where is the start of the list
while(help!=NULL)
    help=help->next;
help=new List;
help->p=new Post()
help->next=NULL
```

why this doesnt work?

sorry for my bad english and if this is too easy .. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem 1:

In your while loop you repeat while `help` is not `NULL`, so you leave the while loop when `help` is `NULL`. You want to keep the last node in the list. The last node is the one where `help->next == NULL`. So your while loop should look like this:

```
while (help->next != NULL)
   help = help->next;
```

Problem 2:

When you set `help = new List();` you lose the reference to the last node in your list. `help` now contains your new `List` instance, but you cannot set it to the `next` entry of your last element in the linked list (the one you searched for in your while loop).

So you may continue with:

```
help->next = new List(); // allocate node and set it as next
help = help->next;       // now you can set help to the new node
help->p = new Post();
help->next = NULL;
```

Note: You should write your while loop with braces - otherwise you may get confused which part of the code is part of the loop and which is not. Eventually this is personal style, but I'd recommend it to beginners:

```
while (help->next != NULL) {
    help = help->next;
}
```